# React List Keys row edit PNPJS dropdown & People Picker

Tags: spfx, react

I am trying to enable row edit for a particular array of People Picker and Dropdown controls. Below is what I have so far,

```
<table cellSpacing="1">
            <div className={styles.tableStyle} >  
            <tr>
              <td className={styles.CellStyle}>Division</td>
              <td className={styles.CellStyle}>Assignee</td>
              <td className={styles.CellStyle}>Added by</td>
            </tr>
          </div> 
            {this.state.ListItems.reverse().map(function(item,key){
              return(<div className={styles.rowStyle} key={item.Id}> 
                <tr>
                  <td><div><Stack tokens={stackTokens}><Dropdown required={true} 
                  onChange={this._getDropdownItem1} 
                  placeholder="Select a Division" 
                  options={this.state.DivisionListItems} 
                  selectedKey={item.Division} 
                  styles={dropdownStyles}  
                  disabled={this.state.isEdit}/>
                  </Stack></div></td>
                  <td>
                    <div><PeoplePicker context={this.props.context} 
                  personSelectionLimit={3} 
                  groupName={""}  
                  showtooltip={true} 
                  tooltipMessage="Select multiple users for assigning the item" 
                  isRequired={true} 
                  disabled={this.state.isEdit} 
                  ensureUser={true} 
                  selectedItems={item.Assignee.map(assigne=>assigne.Title)} 
                  showHiddenInUI={false} 
                  principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]} 
                  defaultSelectedUsers={item.Assignee} 
                  resolveDelay={1000} /></div></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><div><label className='ms-Label'>{item.Author.Title}</label></div></td>
                </tr>
                 <div className={styles.editdiv}><DefaultButton className={styles.button} onClick={()=>{this.handleEdit(item,key)}} iconProps={{iconName:'Edit'}}></DefaultButton><DefaultButton className={styles.button} onClick={()=> { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')){this.handleDelete(item.Id)}  this.onCancel(item) }} iconProps={{iconName:'Delete'}}></DefaultButton></div>
              </div>
                 );
            }.bind(this))}
          </table>
```

> Handle edit function below

```
@autobind
public handleEdit(Division,Users){
  let selectedUsers = [];
   for (let item in Users) {
     selectedUsers.push(Users[item].Title);
   }
  this.setState({editusers:selectedUsers,Dropdownvalue:Division,isEdit:false });
  console.log("event is" + event);
}
```

How do I give unique id to dropdown control and people picker to be able to edit and perform operations only for that row in the array map? I have already given a key for each div which is the unique item.id.

Below is the rendering : Edit is editing the entire dropdown rows instead of that selected one.
[image]

Comment: your button's `onClick` is bound to `{this.handleEdit(item,key)}}`, but `handleEdit` accepts `(Division,Users)` as parameters.  Is this intentional?  Is `Division` equivalent to an `item` and `Users` also the `key`?

Comment: @willman I was able to make it work like that, Yeah the naming in handleedit function parameters need to be changed :). I was able to instantiate another array and fill it up with true on start. Then on edit, I took the index and set the array[index/key] for that row and set it to false. on change wil pass the index and the true or false is set up disabled={this.state.isEdit[index]} but it is still not working even though I am able to see the change in the array from true to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, rather than trying to reference the control, it is better to have your controls reference unique values in State so that you just need to call `setState` when you want to change the way it is rendering.

I would suggest removing the `isEdit` State value, and adding a value such as `editingItemId` to your state, possibly defaulted in your constructor to zero (`0`) or negative one (`-1`).

Then, in your `<Dropdown>` and `<PeoplePicker>` control rendering, instead of setting the `disabled` attribute to `{this.state.isEdit}`, set the it with a conditional expression

```
disabled={item.Id === this.state.editingItemId}
```

You will then need to modify the `setState()` in your `handleEdit` to set `editingItemId` instead of `isEdit`. In fact, since you are already using an arrow function to pass the values, you probably no longer need a separate function, just modify the the `onClick` attribute in your `<DefaultButton>` control to the following:

```
onClick={()=>{this.setState({editingItemId:item.Id })}}
```

You haven't posted what your `_getDropdownItem1` looks like, but I suspect you are going to need it to also accept the current `item` to know which item's value to change.

```
onChanged={selectedOption => { this._getDropdownItem1(item, selectedOption) }}
```

You'll want to do something similar when the value of your `<PeoplePicker>` changes.

Comment: You are awesome!! Worked like a charm....